# ImportError: cannot import name 'Workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I was doing practice with the openpyxl library and out of nowhere I started throwing this error even in the codes that I had already made, for example this hello world

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()

sheet = book.active


sheet['A1'] = 'Hello'
sheet['A2'] = 'World'

book.save('holamundo.xlsx')
```

obviously I already installed the library before

I have This error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import) >
```